# How can I write a JUnit test for below method?

Tags: java, junit

I'm sorry. I'm new to JUnit testing.

This is my method (which I can't modify at all):

```
public class HalfNumber {

    private int value = 41;

    public HalfNumber(){
    };

    public int getHalfValue() {
        int halfValue = value / 2 + value % 2; //gets rounded 

        return halfValue;
     } 
}
```

How can I write a test for getHalfValue() method when doesn't have any parameters but it takes the value from a class variable?

Comment: How would `value` be set in normal execution?

Comment: Hi @nhouser9!!! Value here is define from other operations which are difficult to trace. (so i'm assuming a number of 41, just for the example) Sorry, I know this classes are crazy but I didn't write them and I can't change them neither. But assume that this value number can be any integer.

Comment: Then this class is non-testable, unless you use reflection to set the field and test the individual methods. But that's kind of weird. You should preferably test the whole behaviour of the class, but if it's written with more than one concern in mind this can be difficult, and probably impossible to do right (as in testable, but horribly ugly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @all and thank you for your responses. This is a quick heads up about the solution I found as a workaround for above issue, I hope this works for all of you who had faced a similar situation when you can't modify the java class when creating its correspondent testing class:

```
public class TestHalfNumber {

private HalfNumber classUnderTest;

Map<String,Object> bindingsMap;

protected Map<String, String> captured;
@Mock
protected Resource resource;    
@Mock
protected ResourceResolver resourceResolver;
@Mock
protected SlingHttpServletRequest sServletReq;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * @param object
 *            of type WCMUsePojo. This object cannot be null.
 * @param map
 *            containing properties that needs to be initialized with
 *            WCMUsePojo
 */
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void init(WCMUsePojo obj, Map<String, Object> map) {
    Map<String, Object> staticMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    staticMap.put("resource", resource);

    staticMap.put("request", sServletReq);

    if (map != null)
        staticMap.putAll(map);

    if (obj != null)
        obj.init(new SimpleBindings(staticMap));
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Subclass object is null ");
}


@Before
public void setUp()
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
    classUnderTest = new HalfNumber();  
    when(sServletReq.getResourceResolver()).thenReturn(resourceResolver);   
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Test case for GetHalfValue 
 */
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Test
public void testGetHalfValue() throws Exception{

    int inputValue = 5;
    int expected = 3;

    bindingsMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    //Here is where we change the 4 by a 5 or any other value to test.
    bindingsMap.put("value",inputValue); 

    init(classUnderTest,bindingsMap);
    int result = classUnderTest.getHalfValue();
    Assert.assertEquals(expected,result);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a valid test:

```
@Test
public void numberTest() {
  assertEquals(21, new HalfNumber().getHalfValue());
}
```

By the way, purpose and design of the class is one of the worst I've ever seen.

Comment: Thank you !! I had something like this already. My problem starts when I notice that the value (in this case 41), is the result of some other calculations somewhere above that huge method (I agree it is horrible, but  I didn't write it, I can't change it and my job is only to cover the Java Unit Tests here). So, my next question here is how to mock the value of that variable directly in the class ? In your solution, 21 is always going to be the result and I would like to set a value directly from the testing class.

Comment: Either there is a method that changes the "value" attribute, or you need to access it via the reflection API. What is the purpose, though? Since the class is designed to have a fixed "value" attribute, there is no sense in trying to change it forcefully.